# Definition for Curious Badge

Tags: support, badges

The explanation for the Curious Badge says "Asked a well-received question on 5 separate days, and maintained a positive question record"

What is "well-received" and what is a "positive question record"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Everything is detailed in this meta post on the badges, [Asking days badges](http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/2014/07/july-2014-newsletter/#askingdays).

*excerpt*

> #### well-received question on X separate days
>
> A well-received question is one that's open, not deleted, and has a
>   score > 0. If you ask at least one well-recieved question in a UTC day
>   and none of your questions that day are deleted, downvoted, or closed,
>   you get one more day of credit toward the badge. Whenever the badge
>   criteria is checked, previous asking days are re-evaluated so that
>   there's an incentive to fix downvoted and/or closed questions. The
>   no-deleted-questions criteria is to prevent people from asking several
>   questions at once and deleting any that aren't upvoted or answered to
>   ask another day. (Though this is a losing strategy in the long run.)