# Why am I not being awarded the curious badge?

Tags: support, badges

I have more than 5 questions record and running [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/202517/asking-record?UseIds=1438) on my id (in Unix) says that I have well over 0.5 of "positive question record". But the badge has not been awarded anyway.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Relating https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5198/what-is-curious-badge-and-why-i-am-not-getting-it and https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3085/definition-for-curious-badge as the answer may be in one of those. Will follow up later unless someone else beats me to it.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Read carefully the question. Don't jump to conclusions.

Comment: I haven't concluded *anything*, yet. I linked those two questions to remind me (and you, and everyone reading) that *deleted* questions also appear to count towards the score/badge.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're missing the deleted questions.

As [Michael](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5199/117549) did previously, I took the [apparent formula](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges):

> (total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5

and plugged in your numbers (according to my interpretation, which counted duplicates as also being closed) and came up with a number less than 0.5. I based my "duplicate" decision on [Jon Ericson's comment](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5198/what-is-curious-badge-and-why-i-am-not-getting-it#comment9668_5199):

> @PRY: I considered making an exception for duplicate questions, but decided that worked against the spirit of the badges. Duplicates sometimes help people find the information they are looking for, but the goal of the badge is to encourage new questions.

I think that badges are awarded on a daily basis, so if my assumptions are wrong, it's also possible that you simply need to wait 24 hours for the next cycle.

Forgot to mention: the query in SEDE may have misled you because it doesn't include deleted posts (e.g. questions), thus hiding some of the factors in the calculation.

Comment: Addendum -- I had to click  a few times to find it, but the SEDE help page (https://data.stackexchange.com/help) links to a tutorial (https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) which (on the last page) links to the schema documentation (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/307535) which leads to Jon Ericson's post (https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266431/307535) which says "At the moment, there's no way to see the ClosedDate, tags or titles of deleted questions. Bodies and the various UserIds are also null for deleted posts, for obvious reasons"

Comment: I am saying both things: SEDE does not show you your deleted posts and you have more than 1 deleted questions. I cannot remember if or how you can see them all yourself. I'm not sure if it's appropriate to link them here, so if you'd like a list of them, please let me know (here or in the chat room) and I can try to create a private chat room to list them for you.

Comment: @Isaac https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=deleted%3Ayes+is%3Aq

Comment: @Isaac https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A232326+is%3AQ+deleted%3A1 (the result of going to your profile and adding "is:Q deleted:1" to the user search box) might also help; I just don't remember if it shows you *all* of your deleted Q's or only the most recent ones.

Comment: Socking, just shocking, well, that explains it.

Comment: Yes. it shows all deleted questions, even the ones that someone else has deleted (not me) but belong to me as I asked them.

Comment: @muru Thanks. :-)

Comment: Happy to hear we got to the bottom of it, @Isaac. I edited my comment above to remove the exact number. It's hard to give a good answer to a personal question without going into some level of detail. Let me know if this is all satisfactory. Thanks!