# Where to find the user's statistics of one's own?

Tags: support, badges, statistics

I'd like to find out why I don't get the `Curious` badge on `U&L` with asking a question on 13 of 5 days needed (according to the text in the "badge text field"). It seems to depend on the "maintained a positive question record" part in my case.
I'd like to see how far I'm away from this positive record. Is there a way to get to know about my own statistics of the site, specifically where to find this record?

Comment: I found https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges (from 2014) that describes a formula; I don't know if it's current or not. I don't think there's a "live" statistic on the site; rather, the system awards you the badge when you meet the criteria. Since it's about questions, I'd suggest just scanning the [questions tab of your profile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/154403/nepumuk?tab=questions&sort=newest) and seeing what the formula shows.

Comment: I found "negative questions" as deleted. Do you know whether they count twice (as deleted and as over all negatively voted)?

Comment: According to that post from 2014, deleted & negatively-scored questions would count twice (`total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted`); if it's also closed, that'd count thrice. I'm always cautious to distinguish documentation from code. The system *probably* works like that, but I always allow for the possibility that the code is different from the documentation.

Comment: [previously (2014)](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3085/definition-for-curious-badge), [previously (2019)](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5198/117549), and [previously (2020)](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5542/why-am-i-not-being-awarded-the-curious-badge)

Comment: (I'm now asking this) Just to be sure with this point: the `total questions` don't need any vote up, so the net vote can also be 0 to be counted as desired (for me), right?

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understood your last comment, but: yes, I would assume that `total questions` includes any and all of your questions (negatively scored, 0 scored, and positively scored). I'm not sure what you meant by "... be 0 to be counted as desired...", so let me know if I've missed something or misunderstood you.

Comment: @JeffSchaller a net vote of 0 would mean (for me) that as many users have voted the question up as they have voted it down. A positive net vote would mean that more users have voted the question up than down. A negative net vote would be vice versa.

Comment: I understand what a net vote of 0 *is*; I was confused when you used the word "desired"  for it, in the context of a badge that looks for "a positive question record". If the above equation is correct, then 5 open, non-deleted, zero-scored questions would lead to `(5-0-0-0)/5=1`, so from that point of view, a zero-scored question helps (doesn't hurt) the badge progress.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to see how far I'm away from this positive record. Is there a way to get to know about my own statistics of the site, specifically where to find this record?

As of today, that statistic is not listed explicitly on your profile. You can compute the number yourself, based on the formula given in [Asking days badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges):

> `(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5`

You can use this link to get to your (main U&L, not Meta) profile:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=questions and then count up the corresponding negatively-scored, closed, and deleted (link at the bottom) questions.